# Autoscaling instance in Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

I have a dataset that is going to grow periodically.

I am going to store the data into Google Bigquery and then I want to use Python and pandas to do some analysis and data transformations and put it again in Google Bigquery.

I was thinking to use a cloud compute engine instance to get the data from Google Bigquery. I would start with a small instance and as the data grow, use some cloud function to calculate the size of the data that for example pandas would need to process this data and check if I need to grow the power of the instance, but I don't know if there is a better way to solve this.

I want to know if there is a service in google cloud capable to scale up automatically the power of the instance, because the instance will need more power as data grows.

App engine do that? or app engine only scale out adding more VM?

Cloud run, it's a service that I can use to be triggered to run a docker and it's going to automatically create an instance and scale it up being capable to process the data? it's something that I can use?

Comment: Is your question about how to "autoscale BigQuery" or something else like Compute Engine? There are two types of scaling, "scale up" (more power per instance) and "scale out" (more instances sharing load). Edit your question with more details.

Comment: I think that now is better explained

Comment: The correlation between the amount of data stored in Big Query does not map linearly to compute power required in a compute instance. Google does not offer a service that will autoscale your compute instance larger. You will need to write a function hosted in Cloud Functions or Cloud Run to calculate instance size based upon your custom metrics.

Comment: I can calculate a correlation between the size of the memory RAM that pandas need to process some size of data and make a rule from that? I was thinking may be on use a pyspark code to be more scalable, do you think that is a good idea?

Comment: If you can calculate the correlation between BigQuery dataset size and memory, why not write a simple function to do that? PySpark would be overkill.

Comment: As I said in the question, every day I am going to have more and more data, and the  full table  is going to be analyzed always, so every time I will need more power, is for that I am asking if Pyspark could be a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only vertical autoscaling (Increasing the size of the VM) available is with [pods in Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler). Otherwise, both app engine and compute engine only support [horizontal autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler) (adding more VMs) while the VM is still active. 
Though if your use case allows for the VM to be shut off in order for it to increase the machine size when needed then this is entirely possible.
I'd suggest choosing a large enough machine type to accommodate your data, or use an instance group to spread the weight of your workload, if this is within your use case.